# consecutive read string in server socket using c language

Tags: c

```
             x_hex=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*65);
             bzero(x_hex,65);
             check= read(newsockfd,x_hex,65);
             if ( check < 0)
             error("ERROR reading from socket");
             printf("Bytes recieved: %d\n", check);
             printf("x_hex is %s\n",x_hex);
             BN_hex2bn(&x, x_hex);
             free(x_hex);

             //second read

             y_hex=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*65);
             bzero(y_hex,65);
             check= read(newsockfd,y_hex,65);
             if ( check < 0)
                error("ERROR reading from socket");
             printf("Bytes recieved: %d\n", check);
             printf("y_hex  %s\n", y_hex);
             BN_hex2bn(&y, y_hex);
             free(y_hex);
```

Output-->

//The output should be 64 for x, but here I got 1 only?

```
Bytes recieved: 1
comit1_x_hex from EV driver is 

Bytes recieved: 64
comit1_y_hex from EV driver is 
f0c8ff0cb9872942bc604523cb15243eafe12dc1bdd20339258f2d4eb0bcf1b9
```

Comment: The data you receive, will it be null-terminated? If not, what happens if you receive 65 bytes of unterminated text and try to print it as a null-terminated string?

Comment: And why are you using dynamic allocation here? Why not a normal array?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Since Emmy passes x_hex as a param in a function, I believe that getting the array on the heap is ok and maybe better that have it on the stack.

Comment: What kind of socket/device is `newsockfd`? Many devices (like TCP sockets) have a stream-oriented concept of the data, and are allowed to return partial data. If the server sends 33 bytes, you might see one `read()` of 33 bytes, or a read of 12 bytes followed by a read of 21 bytes, or 33 reads of 1 byte each. Stream-oriented means the transport layer does not preserve any boundaries between chunks of data.

Comment: newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
                       (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,
                       &clilen);
              if (newsockfd < 0)
               error("ERROR on accept");

Comment: I received 1 byte for first string and should be 64 and the value that should be for first string is goes to second read string

Comment: Why should it be 64?

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis Pointers and dynamic allocation adds new possible points of failure and if not careful possible sources of leaks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude true but a memory leak in the Stack is still a memory leak.

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis Local variables are called *automatic* variables for a reason. All their handling (creation, allocation, and *deallocation*) is handled for you by the compiler. The will by definition never leak.